# Problema consumiendo WebService

Tags: c#, webservice, soap

Tengo un problema al consumir un **Web service** desde una aplicación de consola, he agregado el Reference Service (WS) al proyecto, pero al momento de implementarlo dentro del código cuando va a ejecutar el método de ese Web Service me manda el siguiente error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: SOAP header Action was not understood.

Les comparto el AppConfig

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
          <customBinding>
            <binding name="WSAsistenciaSoap">
              <transactionFlow />
              <textMessageEncoding />
              <httpTransport authenticationScheme="Ntlm" />
            </binding>
          </customBinding>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSAsistenciaSoap">
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="direccion.com"
                binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSAsistenciaSoap"
                contract="WSOpenHR.WSAsistenciaSoap" name="WSAsistenciaSoap" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Donde esta tronando es cuando:

```
Cliente.MetodoWS(dato1,dato2);
```

**Nota:** Se requiere autenticación y segun la documentación he agregado `<customBinding>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Les comento que he logrado solucionarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSAsistenciaSoap">
                <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                 <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="direccion.com"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSAsistenciaSoap"
                contract="WSOpenHR.WSAsistenciaSoap" name="WSAsistenciaSoap" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Termine utilizando `<basicHttpBinding>` solo que agregue los siguiente en el **Binding**:

```
                <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                 <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                </security>
```